# Passing Data with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been trying to pass data from my `UICollectionViewController` to my UIViewController under the `prepareForSegue()`. I can do it easily with an UITableView:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "segue"
    {
        let detailViewController = ((segue.destination) as! DetailViewController)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        detailViewController.titleLabelText = titles[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

I've looked through a lot of questions and answers, and I've tried multiple solutions, but none of them have worked. Here's the latest of what I've tried...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
        let detailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        detailViewController.titleLabelText = self.titles[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

But, with this I am getting an error:

> Could not cast value of type
>   'ProjectName.CollectionViewController' to
>   'UICollectionViewCell'.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As the error said, your sender is of type UICollectionViewController rather than UICollectionViewCell. I think you just make a segue from your collectionViewController, which should had to be your collectionViewCell, to your viewController, just check it and redo the segue.

Answer (score 0):

I think in method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

you must be adding :

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your Segue Name", sender: self)
```

Try Changing it to :

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your Segue Name", sender: indexPath)
```

Then in method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

you can get `indexPath` of the cell directly from `sender`